# C# Form部品のDateTimePickerのCustomFormatのMMMを英語表記にできますか？

Tags: c#, winforms

たとえばDateTimePickerのFormatをCustomにして
CustomFormatをdd-MMM-yyに指定することで、
2015/6/23を
23-Jun-15というように表示したいです。

以下の記事のようにPCのコントロールパネルから環境を変更すれば
上記を実現できるのですが、プログラム上で変更できないでしょうか？
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/vstudio/ja-JP/a3c0a8e1-7908-4706-b9f2-9bdb053d3648/datetimepicker

お知恵を拝借できれば幸いです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

サポート情報[KB889834](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/889834)によると`DateTimePicker`のカルチャはOSの設定のみを参照しているため変更不能のようです。